# Alternative derivation for the capacitor energy equation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, energy, electrostatics, potential, capacitance

I hope this is the right place for this kind of post.

A friend is trying to derive the equation for the energy stored in a capacitor by analysing the change in potential on one plate when the capacitor is shorted, however I don't think this valid. Could anyone explain why this is right or wrong?

He says that when the capacitor is shorted the potential at each plate changes by V/2 (from 0 to V/2 on one side and from V to V/2 on the other), so by substituting in V/2 into the equation he gets E = 1/2 QV, the capacitor energy equation.

[image: Diagram]

Comment: I have no idea what the line of reasoning actually is. There might be a good question here, but you need to provide more detail about what your friend is thinking.

Comment: It's not clear what the labels on each plate refer to.  The voltage variable $V$ in the capacitor energy equation refers to the voltage *across* the capacitor.  If one assigns a voltage variable to an individual plate, the first question one must ask is *voltage relative to what?*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your friend's analysis is flawed for an obvious reason as well as a subtle reason.

First, an obvious flaw is labelling each plate with a voltage.  How is this to be interpreted?  For example, with respect to *what* does the right hand plate have voltage $V$?

In essence, your friend is treating each plate as a capacitor in its own right with an associated voltage and thus *stored energy*.  That's OK as long as it is acknowledged as such.  For example:

[image]

Clearly, in the above, we can define a voltage on either conductor, relative to the reference conductor (ground) as well as a voltage across.

But, crucially, *there are 3 capacitors and associated capacitance, voltage, and stored energy to consider.*

And this leads to the subtle flaw which is related to the [two capacitor missing energy paradox](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/35843/a-problem-of-missing-energy-when-charging-a-second-capacitor).

I'll leave that as an exercise for your friend.

Answer (score 0):

The factor of $1/2$ comes because you integrate need to integrate:

$$
E=\int_0^V C V  dV = \frac{1}{2} C V^2 
$$

Comment: This is the standard derivation but he was trying to derive it without integrating.

Comment: Can you explain this derivation?